# How do I separate [npm run watch] and [npm run prod] output (Laravel Mix context)?

Tags: laravel, git, npm, laravel-mix

I am using *Laravel Mix* to compile my frontend assets for development environment `npm run watch` and `npm run prod` when I am ready to push changes to GIT server and deploy to live.

The problem is when I run `npm run watch` my changelist gets contaminated heavily (since all the assets are uncompressed, due to obvious reasons) and I have to stop `npm run watch`, run `npm run prod`, push changes run `npm and run watch` again....

This is quickly got old and boring... I was considering compiling production assets on production server, but this is not possible, since we are practicing zero-downtime deployment keeping live server clean from npm packages and such.

Is there a way to actually be able to run `npm run watch` without interruptions, maybe publish uncompressed assets somewhere else (inject from different folder with `mix()` on dev), compiling production assets before `git commit` (automatically?!)?

This would seriously help me a lot.

Any suggestions highly appreciated!

Comment: What stops you from building your assets on your production server? Since your using zero-downtime deployments, your deployment will be built in a separate folder anyway so what would be the downside of running `npm install` & `npm run production` there?

Comment: You must never commit the files generated by `npm run dev|prod|watch` you should build them as part of your deployment process. I've seen this happen 3 ways: (1) Build things locally and upload them using e.g. `rsync` (2) Checkout your repository on your target server and run `npm install` and `npm run dev|prod` (accordingly) on your server (3) Use an intermediate deployment server which checks out builds and then uploads the code.

Comment: @Remul, I have some of the reasons mentioned in my post. Our production server is not meant and never will be for building resources - serving ONLY. Besides, a lot of uncontrollable things could go wrong while building assets and they could pass sanity and testing checks. The system is mission-critical, we, rather pass a human-test on top of any other tests we can in dev environment.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you for your insigt! Essentially you are saying that we should allocate and maintain an additional server, solely for running `npm run prod`? This is a viable options, but I really don't see any benefits in just running same command locally, but running cost will go up noticeably. We could still consider that if we had not one project like this to deploy...

Comment: If you are hosting multiple apps then it's quite common to maintain an automation server to handle deployments. [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) is quite popular for this purpose. If you only have this one project then running and builds are infrequent or you don't want any automation, then building locally or directly on the production server is probably good enough.  Be mindful though `npm run prod` does use up a significant amount of memory and CPU so be careful not to bring down your production server if you run it in production

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, this was one of the reason we rejected this option. *As I mentioned in my post and in comments to it - building assets on production server was considered and experimented with and rejected due to numerous reasons, like npm wasting and fragmenting space, flaky building behavior, seldom file permission issues etc. Everything uncontrollable on mission-critical live server is not an option... regrettably...*

Comment: I may have to reconsider building assets externally on live or separate deployment server if this is the only viable option... But I am really reluctant to do so, giving my experience in how many stuff can go wrong and the repercussions of that...

Answer (score 0):

You can add `public/js/*` and `public/css/*` to gitignore and compile what you need on the server and after runs `npm run watch` no file will be change affected by git.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post and in comments to it - building assets on production server was considered and experimented with and rejected due to numerous reasons, like npm wasting and fragmenting space, flaky building behavior, seldom file permission issues etc. Everything uncontrollable on mission-critical live server is not an option... regrettably...

Comment: Compiling js assets on production server is bad practice.